# FreeLibrary freeze when using dbExpress (TSQLConnection)

Tags: delphi, dll, dbexpress

I'm currently developing some simple auto-updater app. The most important feature is the possibility of self updating. That's why I plan to put most logic in external DLL. After my DLL grown a little I started to get problems with FreeLibrary call in main app. During dll debugging I've found function responsible for that bug:

```
function TpmDSServerUpdateDownloader.DownloadUpdates: Boolean;
var
  LSQLConnection: TSQLConnection;
  LSQLServerMethod: TSqlServerMethod;
  LUpdatePackageLink: string;
begin
  try
    {$IFDEF DEBUG}
    Sleep(10000);
    {$ENDIF}
    // Getting update package link
    FUpdateServerIP := '127.0.0.1';
    FUpdateServerPort := 8080;
    LSQLConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
    LSQLServerMethod:= TSQLServerMethod.Create(nil);
    LSQLConnection.DriverName :='DataSnap';
    LSQLConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
    LSQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationProtocol=HTTP');
    LSQLConnection.Params.Add('Hostname=' + FUpdateServerIP);
    LSQLConnection.Params.Add('Port=' + IntToStr(FUpdateServerPort));
    LSQLConnection.Params.Add('ConnectTimeout=' + IntToStr(10000));
    LSQLConnection.Connected := True;
    LSQLServerMethod.SQLConnection:= LSQLConnection;
    LSQLServerMethod.ServerMethodName:= 'TServerMethods1.GetUpdatePackageLink';
    LSQLServerMethod.Params[0].AsInteger := 1;
    LSQLServerMethod.ExecuteMethod;
    LUpdatePackageLink := LSQLServerMethod.Params[1].AsString;
    // Downloading update package with LUpdatePackage link
  finally
    LSQLConnection.Connected := False;
    LSQLServerMethod.Free;
    FreeAndNil(LSQLConnection);
  end;
end;
```

The problem appears when I'm using dbExpress components from that function. I'm wondering if freeing the TSQLConnection/TSQLServerMethod leaves some working dbExpress threads/objects like it was with SQLMonitor in IBObjects. Maybe you have some ideas how to solve that? I would be very grateful for help.

Greetings
Michal

Comment: The thing you're wondering about isn't something you need to wonder about. You're already using the debugger, so use it *check* whether there are any threads left over. Please confirm it's a problem *before* asking how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you helpful suggestion. I needed to freeze that project for a moment but now I'm working on it again. I debugged it and I found out that one thread can't terminate properly and is blocking other ones. It's in TDBXScheduler in Data.DBXCommon unit. The program hangs on line 17593 of that unit during unit finalization executed by the main program that uses DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Delphi BUG.

However there is a solution:

following Microsoft closing thread cannot be called from DLL unload, so FreeLibrary freez on WaitForMultipleObject inifinite loop in the TThread.WaitFor proc of the TDBXScheduler which is created in the initialization section of the Data.DBXCommon and going to be auto close in the finialization section of that unit. This makes the error. So we must close that thread earlier.

The solution is you need to export new procedure and call it before FreeLibrary:

```
   uses 
       Data.DBXCommon
    .....
    procedure FinishDLLWork; stdcall; export;
    begin
      TDBXScheduler.Instance.Free;
    end;
```

and call it just before FreeLibrary;
`TDBXScheduler` on freeining `TDBXScheduler.Instance` will auto set it to Nil so this call is fine(check `TDBXScheduler.Destroy;`)

Unfortunately it cannot be called in the `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` or `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` - it is too late.